# How to create a bash script to automatically subtree split part of a repository and push it to another read-only repository

Tags: linux, git, bash, ssh

As I wrote in the object, I have some parts of a component I'm writing that have to be used in other projects.

I don't want to use all the component but only the "common" parts.

So, I created a "Common" folder and in it I put all the common files I need to share across projects.

Now, I need to automatically create a `subtree split` of this folder and push its contents to a read only repository I have on BitBucket.

Just for information: to deal with the authentication part, I've created a new ssh key pair and put the private key in an environment variable: this variable is then used by the bash script to create the file to pass to `ssh-add`. The public key is set in my BitBucket account.

The problem is that the script seems not pushing the splitted code to the remote read-only repository. While executing manually all the commands all works well, I'm not able to make this work in an automated way.

More, as I have never used bash to write script, I'm sure there are a lot of errors in it and that it can be deeply refactored to be better.

Following the code of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd ~/src/bitbucket.org/Aerendir/component-remotes/
echo "> Current working directory: $PWD"

echo '> Creating the key file'
printf %q -v "$ssh_component_remotes_common_key" > bitbucket_key
chmod 400 bitbucket_key
ls ~/src/bitbucket.org/Aerendir/component-remotes/

echo '> Adding the identity for bitbucket.org to config'
cat <<EOT >> ~/.ssh/config
Host bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile ~/src/bitbucket.org/Aerendir/component-remotes/bitbucket_key
EOT
cat ~/.ssh/config

echo '> Adding the key to SSH agent'
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
    spawn ssh-add ${HOME}/src/bitbucket.org/Aerendir/component-remotes/bitbucket_key
    expect "Enter passphrase for key '/home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/Aerendir/component-remotes/bitbucket_key':"
    send "$ssh_component_remotes_common_pass";
    interact
EOF

echo -e '\n > Creating the subtree repository'
mkdir _component-remotes-common
cd _component-remotes-common
git init --bare
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:Aerendir/component-remotes-common.git
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
    spawn git remote show origin
    expect "Enter passphrase for key '/home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/Aerendir/component-remotes/bitbucket_key':"
    send "$ssh_component_remotes_common_pass";
    interact
EOF

echo -e '\n > Splitting in the subtree repository'
cd ../
echo "> Current working directory: $PWD"
git subtree split --prefix=src/Remotes/Common -b split
git push _component-remotes-common split:master

echo '> Pushing to the remote repo'
cd _component-remotes-common
echo "> Current working directory: $PWD"
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
    spawn git push origin master
    expect "Enter passphrase for key '/home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/Aerendir/component-remotes/bitbucket_key':"
    send "$ssh_component_remotes_common_pass";
    interact
EOF

echo "$expect_out(0, string)"
```

And this is the output:

```
> Current working directory: /home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/Aerendir/component-remotes
> Creating the key file
bin            composer.json    docs             phpunit.xml.dist  src
bitbucket_key  composer.lock    log              readmegen.yml     tmp
CHANGELOG.md   CONTRIBUTING.md  phpdoc.xml.dist  README.md
> Adding the identity for bitbucket.org to config
UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
StrictHostKeyChecking=no
ServerAliveInterval 3
ServerAliveCountMax 600
Host bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/src/bitbucket.org/Aerendir/component-remotes/bitbucket_key
> Adding the key to SSH agent
Agent pid 5919
spawn ssh-add /home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/Aerendir/component-remotes/bitbucket_key
Enter passphrase for /home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/Aerendir/component-remotes/bitbucket_key: 
> Creating the subtree repository
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/Aerendir/component-remotes/_component-remotes-common/
spawn git remote show origin
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,104.192.143.2' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/Aerendir/component-remotes/bitbucket_key': 
> Splitting in the subtree repository
> Current working directory: /home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/Aerendir/component-remotes
Created branch 'split'
490b1f471932a308075c568f21c36bab5f102818
Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 36 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 667 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 0), reused 5 (delta 0)
To _component-remotes-common
* [new branch]      split -> master
> Pushing to the remote repo
> Current working directory: /home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/Aerendir/component-remotes/_component-remotes-common
spawn git push origin master
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,104.192.143.3' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/Aerendir/component-remotes/bitbucket_key': (0, string)
```

It seems to work untile the `push`: at that point, I receive no other output. Obviously the remote repo remains empty but I don't know which is the problem as I don't receive any error as output.

I'm working on this script since about 5 hours and I'm very jaded: any help is greatly appreciated to make this work! Thankyou...

Comment: do you really want/need that last `interact` in the `expect` that does the push? Good luck.

Comment: I need it to understand why the push doesn't work.

Comment: so you added it after it failed the first time(s)? I'm not a `git` master, but I would expect there is a verbose option you could set? Add a `pwd` to make sure you in the dir you expect to be. And the other ususal simple debug outputs to confirm all is setup as you expect. That's about all I can think of. Good luck.!

Comment: Yes, the output exists and outside the `expect` it is also outputted, but in the `expect` it isn't... Anyway I abandoned the idea of using subtree split as it creates a lot of problems integrating it in my continuous integration process and for the moment I can go simply developing two separate packages directly, without subsplitting. It's easier and seems to be also more correct and useful (https://mwop.net/blog/2015-05-15-splitting-components-with-git.html).